# Filter legend using custom button outside canvas in vuechart

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I have more than one chart on a single page in my vue application(*vue-chartjs*). What i have to achieve is, by clicking on a single button outside of this canvas, i need to change the chart view. Like clicking on label, we can hide one legend and clicking again that label we can show that legend.

In my case, I have a admin page. There i do have two type of payments from user. One is for calls and other is stickers. Suppose if i have 3 users in that section, there will be three graphs. And label will be like

- Calls
- Stickers

When i click on labels in each graph, it shows only the clicked one. *That works perfectly*. But what i need to achieve is i have two buttons outside canvas, namely

- Show Calls
- Show stickers

On clicking ***Show Calls***, i need to show only ***Calls*** label for *all three graphs*. And viceversa.

**Update 1**

This is one sample i have created. 
[image: test image]

Two button placed top is now static, it should be dynamic. It should get from the label legend of below graph. And color should be same as of grpah label. Now on clicking registration label, it hides the plotting of the currosponding one. But i need to hide all label plotting from 3 graphs, when i click on "Registrations" button

my show-chart.vue

```
<template>
          <chart :chart-data="datacollection" :styles="myStyles"></chart>
</template>
<script>
import Chart from "./../Chart.js";
export default {
  components: {
    Chart
  },
  data() {
    return {
      datacollection: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fillData();
  },
  methods: {
    fillData() {
      this.datacollection = {
        labels: [
          "January",
          "February",
          "March",
          "April",
          "May",
          "June",
          "July",
          "August",
          "September",
          "October",
          "November",
          "December"
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Registrations",
            backgroundColor: "#42b983",
            data: [70, 20, 12, 39, 100, 40, 95, 80, 80, 20, 12, 101]
          },
          {
            label: "Incomes",
            backgroundColor: "#7952b3",
            data: [205, 408, 188, 190, 58, 200, 190, 400, 164, 254, 290, 201]
          }
        ]
      };
    },
  },
 computed: {
myStyles () {
  return {
    height: `500px`,
    width: `350px`,
  }
}
 }
  };
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

my app.vue contains,

```
    <b-button variant="success">Registrations</b-button>

    <b-button variant="success">Incomes</b-button>

    <b-container class="bv-example-row">
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
         <visualisation></visualisation>
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
          <visualisation></visualisation>
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
          <visualisation></visualisation>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
```

Comment: So what's the question/problem? Seems like you just want someone to write this code for you.. Please supply a [CodePen](https://codepen.io) that recreates your issue.. Also, [please see the 'help' on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) - also, please [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well...

Comment: I just want to know, if i can trigger label click from outside of that canvas.

Comment: Can you supply some pseudo code?

Comment: @MattOestreich i have added some sample code.Please have a look.